# How to observe field variable of other class in Mobx flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobx

I am using the flutter Mobx for state management.
I have a simple class:-

```
class A {
  int x;
  A(this.x);
 }
```

How can I observe if `x` changes inside the class in another Mobx store:-

```
class MyStore extends _MyStore  with _$MyStore  {
  Subs(A a) : super(a);
}

abstract class _MyStore  with Store {
  @observable
  A a;
  _Subs(this.a)
}
```

I want `MyStore` to observe the a.x.

Is it possible, if yes how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran in to the same issue the other day using flutter `mobx ^1.2.1+3` (dart) and
`flutter_mobx ^1.1.0+2`.

The first thing that comes to my mind is to annotate the field in question, I.e `x` with the `@observable` attribute. But it doesn't seem to be effective outside a store class.
So you have to observe the field using the Observable class.

To make it work your code should look something like this:

```
class A {
  //replace with less verbose "var"
  Observable<int> x = Observable(0);
  A(this.x);
 }

class MyStore extends _MyStore  with _$MyStore  {
  Subs(A a) : super(a);
}

abstract class _MyStore  with Store {
  
  A a;
  _Subs(this.a)
  
  //Will be calculated whenever a change to a.x is observed.
  @computed
  int get xSquare => a.x.value * a.x.value;
}
```

As you can see I removed the observable attribute from `a`, since it does not need to be observed if you want to react to changes to `a.x` in your store. You probably noticed that you have to access the value of the observable using `.value`.

That should conclude how you observe a field of a class external to the store, inside your store.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this would be helpful since it is Javascript/Typescript, but that's what I would do :

```
class Foo {
  @observable name = 'foo'
}

class Bar {
  foo: Foo

  constructor(instanceOfFoo) {
    this.foo = instanceOfFoo

    autorun(() => {
      // Logs foo name when it changes
      console.log(this.foo.name)
    })

    reaction(
      () => this.foo.name,
      () => {
        // Logs foo name when it changes
        console.log(this.foo.name)
      }
    )
  }

  @observable
  name = 'bar'

  @computed
  get fooNamePlusBarName {
    // recomputes automatically whenever foo or bar name changes
    return this.foo.name + this.name
  }
}
```

Basically you pass `Foo` instance to the `Bar` constructor (or just use imported singleton if it fits you), then you have 3 options: `computed`, `reaction` and `autorun`